# program to show a progress bar while transferring all files from one server to another in java

Tags: java, file

i have written a java code to transfer files from one server to another using the concept of socket programming. now in the same code i also want to check for the network connection availability before each file is transferred. i also want that the files transferred should be transferred according to their numerical sequence. And while the files are being transferred the transfer progress of each file  i.e the progress percentage bar should also be visible on the screen.

i will really appreciate if someone can help me with the code. i am posting the code i have written for file transfer.

ClientMain.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public class ClientMain {
private DirectoryTxr transmitter = null;
Socket clientSocket = null;
private boolean connectedStatus = false;
private String ipAddress;
String srcPath = null;
String dstPath = "";
public ClientMain() {

}

public void setIpAddress(String ip) {
    this.ipAddress = ip;
}

public void setSrcPath(String path) {
    this.srcPath = path;
}

public void setDstPath(String path) {
    this.dstPath = path;
}

private void createConnection() {
    Runnable connectRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (!connectedStatus) {
                try {
                    clientSocket = new Socket(ipAddress, 3339);
                    connectedStatus = true;
                    transmitter = new DirectoryTxr(clientSocket, srcPath, dstPath);
                } catch (IOException io) {
                    io.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    };
    Thread connectionThread = new Thread(connectRunnable);
    connectionThread.start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClientMain main = new ClientMain();
    main.setIpAddress("10.6.3.92");
    main.setSrcPath("E:/temp/movies/");
    main.setDstPath("D:/tcp/movies");
    main.createConnection();

}
```

}

(DirectoryTxr.java)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public class DirectoryTxr {
Socket clientSocket = null;
String srcDir = null;
String dstDir = null;
byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
private InputStream inStream = null;
private OutputStream outStream = null;
int state = 0;
final int permissionReqState = 1;
final int initialState = 0;
final int dirHeaderSendState = 2;
final int fileHeaderSendState = 3;
final int fileSendState = 4;
final int fileFinishedState = 5;
private boolean isLive = false;
private int numFiles = 0;
private int filePointer = 0;
String request = "May I send?";
String respServer = "Yes,You can";
String dirResponse = "Directory created...Please send files";
String fileHeaderRecvd = "File header received ...Send File";
String fileReceived = "File Received";
String dirFailedResponse = "Failed";
File[] opFileList = null;

public DirectoryTxr(Socket clientSocket, String srcDir, String dstDir) {

    try {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        inStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        outStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        isLive = true;
        this.srcDir = srcDir;
        this.dstDir = dstDir;
        state = initialState;
        readResponse(); //starting read thread
        sendMessage(request);
        state = permissionReqState;
    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    }


}

private void sendMessage(String message) {
    try {
        sendBytes(request.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/**
 * Thread to read response from server
 */
private void readResponse() {
    Runnable readRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (isLive) {
                try {
                    int num = inStream.read(readBuffer);
                    if (num > 0) {
                        byte[] tempArray = new byte[num];
                        System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, tempArray, 0, num);
                        processBytes(tempArray);
                    }
                } catch (SocketException se) {
                    System.exit(0);
                } catch (IOException io) {
                    io.printStackTrace();
                    isLive = false;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Thread readThread = new Thread(readRunnable);
    readThread.start();

}

private void sendDirectoryHeader() {
    File file = new File(srcDir);
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        try {
            String[] childFiles = file.list();
            numFiles = childFiles.length;
            String dirHeader = "$" + dstDir + "#" + numFiles + "&";
            sendBytes(dirHeader.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException en) {
            en.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(srcDir + " is not a valid directory");
    }
}


private void sendFile(String dirName) {
    File file = new File(dirName);

    if (!file.isDirectory()) {
        try {
            int len = (int) file.length();
            int buffSize = len / 8;
            //to avoid the heap limitation
            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
            FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();

            int numRead = 0;
            while (numRead >= 0) {
                ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 100000);
                numRead = channel.read(buf);
                if (numRead > 0) {
                    byte[] array = new byte[numRead];
                    System.arraycopy(buf.array(), 0, array, 0, numRead);
                    sendBytes(array);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Finished");

        } catch (IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

private void sendHeader(String fileName) {
    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);
        if (file.isDirectory())
            return;//avoiding child directories to avoid confusion
        //if want we can sent them recursively
        //with proper state transitions

        String header = "&" + fileName + "#" + file.length() + "*";
        sendHeader(header);

        sendBytes(header.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void sendBytes(byte[] dataBytes) {
    synchronized (clientSocket) {
        if (outStream != null) {
            try {
                outStream.write(dataBytes);
                outStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException io) {
                io.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

private void processBytes(byte[] data) {
    try {
        String parsedMessage = new String(data, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(parsedMessage);
        setResponse(parsedMessage);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException u) {
        u.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void setResponse(String message) {
    if (message.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(respServer) && state == permissionReqState) {
        state = dirHeaderSendState;
        sendDirectoryHeader();


    } else if (message.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(dirResponse) && state == dirHeaderSendState) {
        state = fileHeaderSendState;
        if (LocateDirectory()) {
            createAndSendHeader();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Vacant or invalid directory");
        }


    } else if (message.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(fileHeaderRecvd) && state == fileHeaderSendState) {
        state = fileSendState;
        sendFile(opFileList[filePointer].toString());
        state = fileFinishedState;
        filePointer++;

    } else if (message.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(fileReceived) && state == fileFinishedState) {
        if (filePointer < numFiles) {
            createAndSendHeader();
        }
        System.out.println("Successfully sent");

    } else if (message.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(dirFailedResponse)) {
        System.out.println("Going to exit....Error ");
        // System.exit(0);
    } else if (message.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Thanks")) {
        System.out.println("All files were copied");
    }

}

private void closeSocket() {
    try {
        clientSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private boolean LocateDirectory() {
    boolean status = false;
    File file = new File(srcDir);
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        opFileList = file.listFiles();
        numFiles = opFileList.length;
        if (numFiles <= 0) {
            System.out.println("No files found");
        } else {
            status = true;
        }

    }
    return status;
}

private void createAndSendHeader() {
    File opFile = opFileList[filePointer];
    String header = "&" + opFile.getName() + "#" + opFile.length() + "*";
    try {
        state = fileHeaderSendState;
        sendBytes(header.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

    }
}

private void sendListFiles() {
    createAndSendHeader();

}
```

}

(ServerMain.java)

```
public class ServerMain {

public ServerMain() {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    DirectoryRcr dirRcr = new DirectoryRcr();

}
```

}

(DirectoryRcr.java)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;

public class DirectoryRcr {

String request = "May I send?";
String respServer = "Yes,You can";
String dirResponse = "Directory created...Please send files";
String dirFailedResponse = "Failed";
String fileHeaderRecvd = "File header received ...Send File";
String fileReceived = "File Received";
Socket socket = null;
OutputStream ioStream = null;
InputStream inStream = null;
boolean isLive = false;
int state = 0;
final int initialState = 0;
final int dirHeaderWait = 1;
final int dirWaitState = 2;
final int fileHeaderWaitState = 3;
final int fileContentWaitState = 4;
final int fileReceiveState = 5;
final int fileReceivedState = 6;
final int finalState = 7;
byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024 * 100000];
long fileSize = 0;
String dir = "";
FileOutputStream foStream = null;
int fileCount = 0;
File dstFile = null;

public DirectoryRcr() {
    acceptConnection();
}

private void acceptConnection() {
    try {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3339);
        socket = server.accept();
        isLive = true;
        ioStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        inStream = socket.getInputStream();
        state = initialState;
        startReadThread();

    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void startReadThread() {
    Thread readRunnable = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (isLive) {
                try {
                    int num = inStream.read(readBuffer);
                    if (num > 0) {
                        byte[] tempArray = new byte[num];
                        System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, tempArray, 0, num);
                        processBytes(tempArray);
                    }
                    sleep(100);

                } catch (SocketException s) {

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException i) {
                    i.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Thread readThread = new Thread(readRunnable);
    readThread.start();
}

private void processBytes(byte[] buff) throws InterruptedException {
    if (state == fileReceiveState || state == fileContentWaitState) {
        //write to file
        if (state == fileContentWaitState)
            state = fileReceiveState;
        fileSize = fileSize - buff.length;
        writeToFile(buff);


        if (fileSize == 0) {
            state = fileReceivedState;
            try {
                foStream.close();
            } catch (IOException io) {
                io.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Received " + dstFile.getName());
            sendResponse(fileReceived);
            fileCount--;
            if (fileCount != 0) {
                state = fileHeaderWaitState;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Finished");
                state = finalState;
                sendResponse("Thanks");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.exit(0);
            }

            System.out.println("Received");
        }
    } else {
        parseToUTF(buff);
    }

}

private void parseToUTF(byte[] data) {
    try {
        String parsedMessage = new String(data, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(parsedMessage);
        setResponse(parsedMessage);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException u) {
        u.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void setResponse(String message) {
    if (message.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(request) && state == initialState) {
        sendResponse(respServer);
        state = dirHeaderWait;

    } else if (state == dirHeaderWait) {
        if (createDirectory(message)) {
            sendResponse(dirResponse);
            state = fileHeaderWaitState;
        } else {
            sendResponse(dirFailedResponse);
            System.out.println("Error occurred...Going to exit");
            System.exit(0);
        }


    } else if (state == fileHeaderWaitState) {
        createFile(message);
        state = fileContentWaitState;
        sendResponse(fileHeaderRecvd);

    } else if (message.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(dirFailedResponse)) {
        System.out.println("Error occurred ....");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

private void sendResponse(String resp) {
    try {
        sendBytes(resp.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private boolean createDirectory(String dirName) {
    boolean status = false;
    dir = dirName.substring(dirName.indexOf("$") + 1, dirName.indexOf("#"));
    fileCount = Integer.parseInt(dirName.substring(dirName.indexOf("#") + 1, dirName.indexOf("&")));
    if (new File(dir).mkdir()) {
        status = true;
        System.out.println("Successfully created directory  " + dirName);
    } else if (new File(dir).mkdirs()) {
        status = true;
        System.out.println("Directories were created " + dirName);

    } else if (new File(dir).exists()) {
        status = true;
        System.out.println("Directory exists" + dirName);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Could not create directory " + dirName);
        status = false;
    }

    return status;
}

private void createFile(String fileName) {

    String file = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("&") + 1, fileName.indexOf("#"));
    String lengthFile = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("#") + 1, fileName.indexOf("*"));
    fileSize = Integer.parseInt(lengthFile);
    dstFile = new File(dir + "/" + file);
    try {
        foStream = new FileOutputStream(dstFile);
        System.out.println("Starting to receive " + dstFile.getName());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fn) {
        fn.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void writeToFile(byte[] buff) {
    try {
        foStream.write(buff);
    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void sendBytes(byte[] dataBytes) {
    synchronized (socket) {
        if (ioStream != null) {
            try {
                ioStream.write(dataBytes);
            } catch (IOException io) {
                io.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

1. ClientMain.java and DirectoryTxr.java are the two classes under client application. ServerMain.java and DirectoryRcr.java are the two classes under Server application.
2. run the ClientMain.java and ServerMain.java

Comment: Did you read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Which specific part are you having trouble with, and why?

Comment: could you please the code provided and focus on the part that is giving you trouble

Comment: i want to include the code for progress bar for each file transfer and also a code to check for the network availability before each file is transferred. now as i'm new to this concept of socket programming i m having trouble in writing the code.

Comment: There are too many questions here. Part of your question is answered by ProgressMonitorInputastream. There is no such thing as 'check[ing] for network availability'. You just try to connect and it succeeds or it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort an array using `Arrays.sort(...)`

ie

```
String[] childFiles = file.list();
Arrays.sort(childFiles);
```

As I understand it, this will sort the files in [natural order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), based on the file name.

You can modify this by passing a custom `Comparator`...

```
Arrays.sort(childFiles, new Comparator<File>() {...}); // Fill out with your requirements...
```

Progress monitoring will come down to your requirements.  Do you want to see only the overall progress of the number of files, the individual files, a combination of both?

What I've done in the past is pre-iterated the file list, calculated the total number of bytes to be copied and used a [`ProgressMonitor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitor.html) to display the overall bytes been copied...

Otherwise you will need to supply your own dialog.  In either case, you will need use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to update them correctly.

Check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Network connectivity is subjective.  You could simply send a special "message" to there server and wait for a response, but this only suggests that the message was sent and a recipt was received.  It could just as easily fail when you start transfering the file again...

Comment: i want to see the progress bar for each file individually. 
i want to check the network availability before each file starts its transfer and if in between the transfer the connectivity fails then the transfer will be interrupted and that will be shown in the progress bar.

Comment: ProgressMonitor can still do that. As to the connectivity, it still comes down to sending and receiving something and assuming a file transfer succeeds. If either of those two things fail, you should be able to detect it (normally via a IOException). If you need to display more details on the progress dialog, then you will need construct a dialog of your own